# Why do I keep having process abort signal while I deallocated my allocatable array?

Tags: memory-management, fortran, openmp

I changed `threads_list_all` from an array with a constant length to an allocatable array. Since then, It shows me an error.

Here is the subroutine I modified:

```
     subroutine management_16_tasks(tasklist_GRAD,ww,pas,cpt ,nb_element,cpt1,dt,dx,p_element,u_prime,u_prime_moins,u_prime_plus,&
       &taux,grad_x_u,grad_t_u,grad_x_f,grad_t_f,ax_plus,ax_moins,ux_plus,ux_moins,sm,flux,tab0,tab)
    INTEGER ::ff,pas
    INTEGER,intent(inout)::cpt,cpt1,nb_element,ww
    real(kind=REAL64)  :: dt,dx
    integer ,allocatable, dimension(:),intent(inout) ::p_element
    REAL(KIND=REAL64) ,allocatable, dimension(:),intent(inout) :: u_prime,u_prime_moins, u_prime_plus,taux,grad_x_u,&
         &grad_t_u,grad_t_f,grad_x_f,flux,sm
    real(kind=REAL64),allocatable,dimension(:),intent(inout) :: ax_plus,ax_moins,ux_moins,ux_plus
    REAL(KIND=REAL64) ,allocatable, dimension(:,:),intent(inout) ::tab0,tab
    type(tcb)::self
    !OpenMP variables
    integer::num_thread,nthreads
    integer, external :: OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM, OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS    
    type(tcb),dimension(20)::tasklist_GRAD,tasks_ready_master
    !Variables pour gestion des threads 
    integer,allocatable,dimension(:)::threads_list !liste contenant les nums des threads workers 
    integer,allocatable,dimension(:)::threads_list_all !liste contenant les nums des threads workers dans l'ordre selon les tâches  
    integer,dimension(16)::threads_list_part3 ! le reste des tâches
    !=======================================================================================================================================================
    !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(num_thread,threads_list,threads_list_all) &
    !$OMP SHARED(tasklist_GRAD,tasks_ready_master) &
    !$OMP SHARED(threads_list_part3,nthreads)
    num_thread=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM() ! le rang du thread
    nthreads=OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS() ! le nombre de threads


    !Thread Application Master (numero 1)
    if (num_thread==1) then
       do ff=5,20 ! 16 tâches 
          if (associated(tasklist_GRAD(ff)%f_ptr) .eqv. .true.) then
             tasks_ready_master(ff) = tasklist_GRAD(ff) 
             tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_READY
          end if
       end do
    end if
    !$OMP BARRIER 

    !Thread Master (numero 0)
    if (num_thread==0) then

       allocate(threads_list(nthreads-2)) ! liste des threads workers 
       do ff=1,nthreads-2
          threads_list(ff)=ff+1
       end do


       do ff=5,20,nthreads-2
          if (tasks_ready_master(ff)%state==STATE_READY) then
             if (.not. allocated(threads_list_all)) allocate(threads_list_all(nthreads-2))
             threads_list_all(ff-4:ff+nthreads-7)=threads_list(:)
          end if
       end do
       threads_list_part3=threads_list_all(1:16) ! 16 tâches
       deallocate(threads_list_all)
       deallocate(threads_list)

    end if
    !$OMP BARRIER

    !Threads workers
    do ff=5,20
       if (num_thread==threads_list_part3(ff-4)) then
          call tasks_ready_master(ff)%f_ptr(self,ww,pas,cpt ,nb_element,cpt1,dt,dx,p_element,u_prime,u_prime_moins,u_prime_plus,&
               &taux,grad_x_u,grad_t_u,grad_x_f,grad_t_f,ax_plus,ax_moins,ux_plus,ux_moins,sm,flux,tab0,tab)
          tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_RUNNING
       end if
       !$OMP BARRIER 
    end do

    !Thread Master (numero 0)
    if (num_thread==0) then
       do ff=5,20
          if (tasks_ready_master(ff)%state==STATE_RUNNING) then
             tasklist_GRAD(ff)%state=STATE_RUNNING   
          end if
       end do
    end if
    !$OMP END PARALLEL 
  end subroutine management_16_tasks
```

I allocated it using `allocate(threads_list_all(nthreads-2))` and deallocated it using `deallocate(threads_list_all)`.
You can find the allocation line in the part under the comment `!Thread Master (numero 0)`.
The error I get is:

```
malloc(): corrupted top size

Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7ff01ae1e700 in ???
#1  0x7ff01ae1d8a5 in ???
#2  0x7ff01aabd20f in ???
#3  0x7ff01aabd18b in ???
#4  0x7ff01aa9c858 in ???
#5  0x7ff01ab073ed in ???
#6  0x7ff01ab0f47b in ???
#7  0x7ff01ab12839 in ???
#8  0x7ff01ab15d14 in ???
#9  0x7ff01ae1dbf6 in ???
#10  0x7ff01b058547 in ???
#11  0x7ff01b05879f in ???
#12  0x7ff01b04fa38 in ???
#13  0x55df8b75a313 in hecese
    at /home/hakim/stage_hecese_HPC/OpenMP/OpenMP_hecese_OpenMP.f90:1244
#14  0x55df8b7521fe in main
    at /home/hakim/stage_hecese_HPC/OpenMP/OpenMP_hecese_OpenMP.f90:804
Abandon (core dumped)
```

The full code is on https://gitlab-sds.insa-cvl.fr/houeslat/stage_hecese/-/blob/master/OpenMP/OpenMP_hecese_OpenMP.f90.

Comment: This is a classic case of heap corruption. Most often caused by accessing your arrays of bounds or by using incorrect pointers. Impossible to say more without debugging the full code. Compile your code with all debugging flags.

Comment: @VladimirF I used -fbounds-check and I think that I found the problem. Thanks !

Comment: Giving such a big code in a lonk is useless. Instead, create a [mcve] that can fit here.

Comment: @ Okay thanks for the remark ! I have a little question. I'm having the error "Attempting to allocate already allocated variable 'threads_list_all' " now. My question is : is it possible to allocate an array inside a loop ? since I want to allocate it by nthreads-2 at each iteration. Is it possible ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. You can only allocate or deallocate an array once in one go. You cannot do it by parts. It does not matter if that is in a loop or elsewhere. Note that allocation is likely not thread safe. Surely not for a shared array.

Comment: @VladimirF so if I understand well your answer, it's better (in the point of view of thread safety and performances) to keep a constant length (even if it's bigger than the real one) than using allocation ?

Comment: It depends on too many factors. Impossible to state in general.

Comment: For allocation if the array size needs to change or (the maximum size) can't be determined at compile time, then make it allocatable. But I would say for thread safety and performance make as many things private as reasonably possible - your default should be to have things private and only make them shared if required.

Comment: Oh, and by that I do not mean use default ( private ) when scoping variables at the start of a parallel region - I personally much prefer default( none ).